# Consistent behaviour of the ++ operator in C#

Tags: c#, increment, integer-overflow

Is the behaviour of the `++` operator as applied to longs in C# consistent when it is applied to `long.MaxValue`? The call is not made inside a `checked` block. I need to know if *under any circumstances, present or future* it could possibly throw an `OverflowException` instead of wrapping to `long.MinValue`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even if you're not inside a `checked` block, if you compile your project with "Check for arithmetic overflow/underflow" in Visual Studio (or use the [/checked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h25wtyxf.aspx) C# compiler switch), then all your code will behave as if it was inside a `checked` block by default.  So you could absolutely get an overflow exception in that case.

Comment: So using `unchecked { _qualifier++; }` instead of `_qualifier++;` would be a better solution, just in case someone at some point changes the compiler setting?

Comment: Yes, that would ensure consistent behavior.

Answer (score 2):

From C# language specification:

> For non-constant expressions (expressions that are evaluated at run-time) that are not enclosed by any checked or unchecked operators or statements, the default overflow checking context is unchecked unless external factors (such as compiler switches and execution environment configuration) call for checked evaluation.